# Which finite fields admit a non-identity automorphism (endomorphism)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field of cardinality $p^n$ for some prime number $p$. Under what conditions $F$ admits a non-identity automorphism (endomorphism)?

Comment: $n>1$ works here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean for any $n>1$ then $F$ has a non-identity automorphism and also a non-automorphism endomorphism?

Comment: It has a non-identity automorphism, is what I meant. For endomorphisms, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201951/the-endomorphism-of-field

Comment: @GerryMyerson That post concerns infinite fields.

Comment: I don't think you read the whole thing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the function $\phi:F\rightarrow F$ by $\phi(x)=x^p$. Under what circumstances is this an automorphism?  (It is called the *Frobenius automorphism*.)

If you can find the conditions under which $\phi$ is an automorphism, the next step is to determine when it is a non-identity automorphism.   To do this, think about its order in the automorphism group.

Finally, you've handled almost all of the cases; what's left is to show that a very specific type of field doesn't have non-trivial automorphisms.

Comment: I am not looking for a proof. Just a statement of a theorem would be  enough.

Comment: Okay.  Then the result is that the Frobenius automorphism is (in fact) an automorphism of $F$ under any conditions on $p$ and $n$; it is non-trivial in the case where $n>1$.  In the case $n=1$, there are no non-trivial field automorphisms.