# Field homomorphisms and automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I have the following proven theorem:

> Let $L:K$ be a finite field extension and $\phi: K\xrightarrow{} L'$ a field homomorphism. Then there exist at most $[L:K]$ different field homomorphism $\widetilde{\phi}: L\xrightarrow{} L'$ with $\widetilde{\phi}\big|_{K}=\phi$.

Where $[L:K]$ denotes the dimension of $L$ over $K$.

Now my question is:

> If I set $L=L'$ and $\phi =id$, the identity, will then $\widetilde{\phi}$ automatically become a field automorphism?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201951/the-endomorphism-of-field

Comment: If $[L:K]$ is finite, then any field endomorphism of $L$ that is an automorphism on $K$ is an automorphism of $L$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and how would one prove this fact?

Comment: @vaoy $L$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$. For such spaces, every injective endomorphism is an automorphism.

Comment: Ohh yes. Linear algebra stuff. If you do not mind writig it as an answer I wouod check this question as answered. Thanks!